# Exclude node_modules but include one folder

Tags: javascript, webpack, es6-module-loader

I'm trying to make this [emoji-picker](https://github.com/OneSignal/emoji-picker) work. But since it's a in node_modules I can't access it. My question is how to include only the folder that contains the emoji-picker files? here is my webpack

```
var path = require('path')

module.exports = {
 entry: './src/js/app.js',
 output: {
  filename: 'build.js',
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
 },
 devServer: {
   contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
  port: 4000,
  public: 'localhost:4000'
 },
 devtool: 'cheap-eval-source-map',
 module: {
  rules: [
   {
    // set up standard-loader as a preloader
    enforce: 'pre',
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    loader: 'standard-loader',
    exclude: /(node_modules)/,
     // how to make this one work? so I can access it
    include: path.resolve(__dirname, '/node_modules/onesignal-emoji-picker/'),
    options: {
      // Emit errors instead of warnings (default = false)
      error: false,
      // enable snazzy output (default = true)
      snazzy: true
    }
  },
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
  },
  {
    test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
    use: [
      'file-loader'
    ]
  }
]
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You're providing two conditions (`include` and `exclude`) that will never be matched at the same time.

From the [docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#rule-conditions):

> When using multiple conditions, all conditions must match.

Try to use a single condition, something like:

```
exclude: /node_modules\/(?!.*onesignal-emoji-picker).*$/
```

Comment: I did that but when I tried to link it, it didn't work  <link href="/node_modules/onesignal-emoji-picker/lib/css/emoji.css" rel="stylesheet"> error saying file not found

Comment: You can only reference assets that are built to your output directory. To emit CSS files, you'll have to import them and use the [extract-text-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin)